# Relationship between Eager Execution and tf.function

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

My code is distributed across several files and functions and so it is not practical to refer to it over here. I think, I can solve it on my own if I understand eager execution and tf.function very well. Could someone help me here with the following queries ?

1. Does @tf.function decorator work only when eager execution is disabled ?
2. What is the relationship between @tf.function decorator and eager mode of execution ?
3. How does TensorFlow switch between eager mode and non-eager mode internally ? When I disable eager execution, and I have some error in my code, I still get reference to files which suggest to me that eager execution might be happening internally.

Answer (score 3):

Let me try to explain it. Hope it will be useful.

- @tf.function decorator work only when eager execution is disabled ?
  **no, actually tf.function is something to accelerate execution when eager mode is enabled**
- What is the relationship between @tf.function decorator and eager mode of execution ?
  **@tf.function will cause tensorflow autograph working and accelerate execution for those operation inside it.**
- How does TensorFlow switch between eager mode and non-eager mode internally ?
  **tf.function and AutoGraph work by generating code and tracing it into TensorFlow graphs. So when you call a @tf.function decorated function the first time, tensorflow will first convert it into a graph, then execute it, after that, when you can the function again, it will just execute the graph.**

You can also check the tensorflow documentation.
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function

Comment: So, what happens when you disable the eager execution ? How does tf.function behave in that case. And how does TensorFlow code as a whole behaves without eager execution ?

Comment: eager mode is something introduce in later version of Tensorflow, when eager mode is disabled, tf operators will be built into graph for fast execution, it can be triggered through session.run(xx), tf Keras model.fit() and estimator.

Comment: I've noticed if I turn on tf.function for a function, I cannot print out the values of the tensor's items in them. That is, if I am producing a loss function value in a method annotated with tf.function, the loss is a tf.tensor when I print. Whereas without, I get the actual floating point value.